# Join a surface and a density plot

Tags: plotting, graphics

My question is if it's possible to do something like this with Mathematica:

[image]

I know that it is possible to plot a surface with Plot3D and a 2D plot with DensityPlot, so I was wondering how to join them.
Thanks!

Comment: that's right, thanks!